# Flutter, Cannot Build For iOS: Missing .h-Files

Tags: ios, flutter, build

Building our Flutter project fails on iOS. The following steps work without problems:

- running on the XCode simulator (flutter run)
- building in the terminal (flutter build ios)
- running on a real device in debug mode (flutter run -d "abcd")

If I open the project in XCode, change the build target to "Generic iOS Device" and hit "Build" or "Archive" I get the following error:

/Users/.../development/testproject/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:6:9: 'flutter_exif_rotation/FlutterExifRotationPlugin.h' file not found

After removing the FlutterExifRotationPlugin, the error reoccurs with the next plugin alphabetically, so I figured that plugins in general don't work at the moment.

I tried:

- dev, stable and master channels of flutter
- reinstalling XCode
- reinstalling Flutter
- create a new project and moving the old files there

But nothing worked so far.

Answer (score 2):

Ok the solution was very simple. I had to open the .xcworkspace file instead of the .xcodeproject one.

One WEEK went down the pipe for this error. I hope that you, future reader, will find this comment useful.

Comment: Brilliant. Luckily I didn't lose as much time. There's quite a few issues out there asking about this issue - this was the solution for me. Phew! Thanks